# Accidental coincidence formula

Tags: experimental-physics, probability, statistics, signal-processing

Suppose you have a setup with $n$ scintillators coupled with $n$ PMTs. These signals are passed to a discriminator. I am observing some signal, let's say this signal is coming from cosmic rays and I want to estimate the rate of accidental coincidences between the detectors.

Suppose $n=2$ for simplicity. I know the formula for the accidental coincidence $AC$:
$$\tag{1}
AC = 2\tau R_1R_2
$$
Where $\tau$ is the time width of the signal coming from the discriminator, $R_i$ is the rate of the $i$-th scintillator.
Intuitively I would say that $AC$ is the probability that the second scintillator detects something times the elapsed time of the first one while it was activated, so:
$$\tag{2}
AC = \tau R_1 R_2
$$
The factor $2$ is missing here and I don't know why.
A more general formula takes into account that the two discriminated signals may not have the same time amplitude $\tau$, so the equation I've found on my professor's slides is:
$$\tag{3}
AC = R_1 R_2 (\tau_1 + \tau_2 - 2\delta\tau)
$$
Where $\delta\tau$ is the minimum time required by the discriminator module. Why do you have to subtract that time (two times)?

What I am looking for is a valid method to obtain the correct formula of the accidental coincidence rate, eventually for a setup with $n$ scintillators.

I am grateful to anyone who will try to help me.

Comment: Are you interested in the coincidence rate for all $n$ counters firing at the same time, or any two of the $n$ counters being coincident? Isn't the factor of 2 in Eq. (1) because the second pulse must avoid a $2\tau$ wide interval to avoid a coincidence? This is because if $\tau$ is the width of the pulse, then the two pulses will have some overlap if the centre of the second pulse is within $-\tau$ to $+\tau$ of the centre of the first pulse.

Comment: I want a formula for the accidental rate of all the $n$ scintillators. Concerning the second part of the comment I think I’m starting to figuring out why the 2 appears and why there is also the $-2\delta\tau$ factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given in ["Accidental Coincidences in Counter Circuits"](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.53.752) is:
$$AC(n) = \prod_{i=1}^n R_i \tau_i \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\tau_i}$$
This formula agrees with your equation (3) for $n=2$ and $\delta t = 0$. If all the scintillators have equal pulse widths ($\tau_i =\tau$) and equal rates ($R_i=R$), it reduces to:
$$AC(n) = nR_i^n \tau^{n-1}$$

For non-zero $\delta t$, I believe you just need to replace $\tau_i$ by $(\tau_i-\delta t)$ in the formula. You'll want to look at the paper, but my understanding is that it assumes the discriminator output widths are fixed (e.g. not [constant fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_fraction_discriminator)) and the rates are low enough that [dead time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_time) and [updating](https://books.google.ca/books?id=2mq94rdFd3gC&pg=PA77) are not an issue.

If your situation is more complicated, you might want to look at ["On some problems in the counting statistics of nuclear particles: Investigation of the dead time problems"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nima.2012.07.036) or Schrödinger and Janossy's discussion of the ["Rate of n-fold Accidental Coincidences"](https://www-nature-com.myaccess.library.utoronto.ca/articles/153592b0).